# how to get value from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

This is a php array in some object I have to simply fetch the contact
value from this standard array of PHP. Only contact value not the name
value so how can I get value of all contact from this object. I want
only contact value from the contact key.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [contactlist] => Array
        (
            [0] => {
    contact = 4155553695;
    name = "Kate Bell";
}
            [1] => {
    contact = 4085553514;
    name = "Daniel Higgins";
}
            [2] => {
    contact = 8885551212;
    name = "John Appleseed";
}
            [3] => {
    contact = 5555228243;
    name = "Anna Haro";
}
            [4] => {
    contact = 7075551854;
    name = "Hank Zakroff";
}
            [5] => {
    contact = 5556106679;
    name = "David Taylor";
}
            [6] => {
    contact = 542222222222;
    name = Deepak;
}
        )

)
```

Comment: objectname->contactlist[0];

Answer (score 2):

You can try use this UPDATED solution

```
$result = array();
foreach ($object->contactlist as $k=>$v){
   preg_match('/(\d+)/s', $v, $contact);
   $result[] = $contact[0];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Hello i am not getting the contact value instead of it i got  this ' { '  in array.

Comment: @GauravJhaloya You know what `var_dump` does?

Comment: Yes i know it simply print array with his type.

Comment: {
    contact = 4155553695;
    name = "Kate Bell";
} 


is it string value or json encoded value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regex to extract the value.  Try the following:

```
foreach ($obj->contactlist as $contactInfo) {
    preg_match('~^\s*contact\s*=\s*(\d+);$~m', $contactInfo, $matches);
    $contact = $matches[1];
    echo $contact . '<br />';
}
```

It will match a string in the format of 'contact = 123;' and extract the matching digits.

Read more here: http://php.net/preg_match

> preg_match — Perform a regular expression match
>
> **Usage**: *int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )*